# Return query result state from PostgreSQL query in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have a `node.js` server connected to a PostgreSQL database using the `pg` module. At one point I will insert data into two different database tables for a single `HTTP POST`. If the first query fails, the second should not be executed, but I have some trouble achieving this.

My generalized query function looks like this:

```
// General insertion function. If endResponse is true, the response will be ended,
// if it is false it will just write to the response and not end it (unless errors occurs).
function performInsertQuery(request, response, query, endResponse) {
    var pg = require('pg');

    var client = new pg.Client(request.app.get('postgreConnection'));
    client.connect(function(error) {
        if (error)
        {
            message = 'Could not connect to PostgreSQL database: ' + error;
            response.end(message);
            console.error(message);
            client.end();
        }
        else
        {            
            client.query(query, function (error, result)
            {
                if (error)
                {
                    var message = 'Error running query ' + query + ': ' + error;
                    response.writeHead(500, {'content-type':'application/json'});
                    response.end(message);
                    console.error(message);
                    client.end();
                }
                else
                {
                    var message = 'Query performed: ' + query;
                    if (endResponse)
                    {
                        response.end(message);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.write(message + '\n');
                    }
                    console.log(message);
                    client.end();
                }

            });
        }
    });
}
```

Later, I have something like the following:

```
// query = some query
performInsertQuery(request, response, query, false);

// Stop running here if there was any errors running the query.

// Currently, this gets executed even though the first query fails.
// anotherQuery = another query
performInsertQuery(request, response, anotherQuery, true);
```

I have tried returning `true` and `false` from the function `performInsertQuery`, but since these are inner functions the result is not returned properly from the outer functions. Also, some if it is run asynchronously, which makes things a bit harder as well. I was not able to make it work with `try/catch` around the call to `performInsertQuery` either. I guess I could do another query to see if data was inserted, but this seems unnecessary and not very robust.

What would be the best way to return a success or failure state from `performInsertQuery`?

Comment: There are simply too many issues with your code to list here, starting with the wrong approach to PG library instantiation, the wrong connection usage, the wrong invocation of `client.end()`, etc. If you want to avoid that kind of unholy mess you're in, give a try to [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), which should hide all the complexities related to connection and query sequencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this doesn't exactly handle your question as you intended(dealing with this entirely in node.js), but this sounds like an excellent usecase for a Postgres transaction....Do not commit results unless all insertions/updates are successful. SQL transactions are built for scenarios like yours.

Here are the docs and example code for it with your node module.
https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/Transactions

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/tutorial-transactions.html

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about transactions. I think this is a more robust way to solve my problems. I only add a `BEGIN` to the beginning of the total query and an `COMMIT` at the end and keep the insertion function as in the question. Works perfectly.

Comment: If the author formulated his question correctly, then this answer is incorrect. Use of a transaction may result in a situation when the first query succeeds, and the second one fails, which will `ROLLBACK` the result of the first query also, which isn't what the author asked for.

Comment: Well, it is what I *wanted* to ask, I just didn't know how to because I am a JavaScript noob and did not know about transactions or how they worked. Anyway, you are correct that using `pg-promise` or other `promise` libraries is a way better option than the approach I have in the question. I didn't know about promises and related stuff either, but now I do. Thanks.